# Data show by list when group by is not include data

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a sql command like this

```
select mainPOID.EstAPDate,mainPOID.POID,TTm.ID,TTMAmount=TTMD.InvoiceAmount
From TTBeforeMms TTM
inner join  TTBeforeMms_Detail TTMD   on TTM.ID = TTMD.ID
inner join (
select  distinct main.EstAPDate,main_D.POID
From AP main
left join  AP_Detail  main_D on main.ID = main_D.ID
where  main.Type ='PA' and  main.EstAPDate between '2018/6/01' AND '2018/6/15' and  left(main_D.InvoiceNo,4) != '1111' ) mainPOID on TTMD.poid =mainPOID.POID and TTM.EstAPdate<=mainPOID.EstAPdate and  mainPOID.POID='CM3PU18030009'
order by mainPOID.EstAPDate,mainPOID.POID
```

sql result will like this

[image]

My question is
How can Data show by list when group by is not include data?

For example

ID will show by list  When I group by EstAPDate、POID and sum(TTMAmount)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store in one temp table or use `CTE`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].#Columnss(
    espapdate date   ,
    poid  varchar(max),
    id  varchar(max),amount decimal(22,6))

GO
insert into #Columnss values('2018-06-15','cm3','pt20',19988.8900)
insert into #Columnss values('2018-06-15','cm3','pt21',265.8900)

    SELECT 
    REPLACE(ESPAPDATE,'-','/') ESPAPDATE, POID,
    STUFF(
        (SELECT ' , ' + OD.ID 
        FROM #COLUMNSS OD 
        WHERE OD.ESPAPDATE = O.ESPAPDATE
        AND  OD.POID = O.POID
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
    ) PRODUCTNAMES,SUM(AMOUNT)AMOUNT
FROM #COLUMNSS O 
GROUP BY ESPAPDATE, POID
```

output

```
   espapdate    poid    ProductNames    amount
    2018/06/15  cm3     pt20 , pt21     20254.780000
```

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of CSV example using FOR XML PATH. For your case here, i am wrapping your existing query in a CTE and then from there generate the CSV string for ID

```
; with 
cte as
(
select      mainPOID.EstAPDate, mainPOID.POID, TTm.ID, TTMAmount=TTMD.InvoiceAmount
From        TTBeforeMms TTM
inner join  TTBeforeMms_Detail TTMD   on TTM.ID = TTMD.ID
inner join  (
                select  distinct main.EstAPDate,main_D.POID
                From    AP main
                     left join  AP_Detail  main_D on main.ID = main_D.ID
                 where  main.Type ='PA' 
                 and    main.EstAPDate between '2018/6/01' AND '2018/6/15' 
                 and    left(main_D.InvoiceNo,4) != '1111' 
            ) mainPOID  on TTMD.poid      = mainPOID.POID 
                       and TTM.EstAPdate <= mainPOID.EstAPdate 
                       and mainPOID.POID  = 'CM3PU18030009'
)
SELECT  EstAPDate, POID, 
        ID = STUFF(c.ID, 1, 1, ''),
        TTMAmount = SUM(TTMAmount)
FROM    cte 
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT ',' + ID
            FROM   cte x
            WHERE  x.EstAPDate = cte.EstAPDate
            AND    x.POID      = cte.POID
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) c (ID)
GROUP BY EstAPDate, POID
ORDER BY EstAPDate, POID
```